# GlassFish não pega context root da aplicação

Tags: java, aplicação-web, glassfish

**EDIT**
Galera eu consegui resolver, estava faltando apontar minha aplicação para meu virtual server, obrigado.

Subi uma aplicação no servidor hoje e o glassFish não está pegando o contexto da aplicação sozinho por exemplo para acessar estou tendo que colocar : *www.blabla.com/Atendimento*.

```
<glassfish-web-app>
<context-root>/Atendimento</context-root>

<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />

<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/backgrounds/* dir=e:\HRatendimento\imagens\" />
<property name="alternatedocroot_2" value="from=/logos/* dir=e:\HRatendimento\imagens\" />
<property name="alternatedocroot_3" value="from=/gerais/* dir=e:\HRatendimento\imagens\" />
<property name="alternatedocroot_4" value="from=/anexos/* dir=e:\HRatendimento\imagens\" />
<property name="alternatedocroot_5" value="from=/usuarios/* dir=e:\HRatendimento\imagens\" />
<property name="alternatedocroot_6" value="from=/licenca/* dir=e:\HRatendimento\" />
<property name="alternatedocroot_7" value="from=/manuais/* dir=e:\HRatendimento\" />
```

E no glassFish eu deixei o contextRoot como `/Atendimento`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Tente editar o context root no console (porta 4848). Se não funcionar tire um screen das configurações no console e mostre do seu `glassfish-web.xml` (todo o conteúdo, bem como a pasta em que ele está localizado). Se o objetivo for jogar na raiz do site, basta setar o context-root para `/ `.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly novamente me ajudando, então essa aplicação funcionava tranquilo, eu fiz esse deploy hoje e aconteceu isso, poém eu não fiz alteração nessas configurações

Comment: Entendi. Só para poder te ajudar melhor. O objetivo é eliminar o `/Atendimento` e publicar na raiz? Ou é para ficar onde está só que está acontecendo algum problema?

Comment: Sim publicar na raiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No GlassFish o sinônimo para raiz é `/`.

Você pode setar esse contexto de várias maneiras:

1. Por arquivos de configuração como o `glassfish-web.xml`:

   ```
   <glassfish-web-app>
       <context-root>/</context-root>
   </glassfish-web-app>
   ```
2. Pelo console administrativo como demonstrado na sua pergunta.
3. Pelo `asadmin` na hora de publicar sua aplicação:

   ```
    asadmin deploy --contextroot "/" Atendimento.war
   ```
4. Do seu IDE (geralmente existe alguma opção para trocar o `context-root` nas configurações de deploy).

Comment: Troquei /Atendimento por apenas "/" e funcionou, porém ele está perdendo todas as imagens :(

Comment: Aí não sei dizer Wellington, talvez você tenha fixado caminho de recursos na aplicação. O interessante é sempre deixá-los relativos e considerar o contextPath: e.g., `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/logo.png`.

Comment: '<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/backgrounds/* dir=e:\HRatendimento\imagens\" />' esta assim, mas sua resposta está correta, novamente muito obrigado, vou tentar descobrir o porque está perdendo o caminho.

Comment: Eu não quis dizer os docroots (mas verificar se essas pastas contém o arquivo pode ajudar). Acredito que dentro do próprio markup o caminho para suas iagens estejam errados. E.g., `/Atendimento/backgrounds/meufundodetela.jpg`. Mas de qualquer forma é chute; se não conseguir resolver abre uma pergunta com as informações relevantes (estruturas de pasta, caminhos dentro do html gerado, configurações, etc) que tenho certeza que o pessoal descobre ;).

Comment: Galera só para conhecimento de todos eu consegui arrumar, estava faltando apontar para meu virtual server do serviço.